# Merge tags "abroad" and "offshore" into tag "international" and establish tag synonyms?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Do we really need the [abroad](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abroad) and [offshore](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offshore) tags? We already have the [international](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international) tag which is used far more often than either of the aforementioned.

Answer (score 5):

Agreed. In principle [offshore](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offshore) has slightly more specialised connotations than [international](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international) but I don't think it's worth it to try to draw the distinction in practice.

[edit: tags now merged and synonyms added]